# Read and Write permission for storage and gallery usage for marshmallow

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, read-write

I am developing an android app in which it is required to provide permission for Read and write external storage. My requirement is to select a picture from gallery and use it in my app. Everything is working fine except Marshmallow devices. I want to provide permission for Marshmallow. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Permission doesn't change according to os level. it  is same as below.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: i have already given that permission in my manifeast.. but app crashes when marshmallow user select image from gallery..saying permission dined

Comment: its not matter that permission is different. it is about you have to ask to user in marshmallow about permission at runtime

Comment: thts what i am asking

Comment: Khan gave you answer below that pretty much good

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It can be achieved something as following...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback{

  private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION = 786;

  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {            
        openFilePicker();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    requestPermission();
  }

  private void requestPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION);
    } else {
        openFilePicker();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Somebody down-voted this answer, May I know the reason? I will try to improve.

Comment: It is heavily suggested to also include android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in the checks and permission requests. There are certain rare scenarios where WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is granted but READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is denied.

Answer (score 2):

Read through [Runtime permissions - Android M](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) and [its reference project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions).

Permissions flow has changed requiring the permissions to be asked at runtime, preferably, as and when required. With the same.. permissions have also been categorised into [Normal and Dangerous](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous) which will also lead to permission groups.

Answer (score 1):

For writing a file in storage,
First,need to add write permission in **manifest.xml**,

Then,
In Android 6, it contains a permission system for certain tasks. Each application can request the required permission on runtime. So let’s open Activity class add below code for requesting runtime permission.

check your application has a runtime write permission using,

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray) {

    when(requestCode)  {

        100 -> {
            if (grantResults.size > 0 && permissions[0] == Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check AndroidManifest.xml!!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android.yoganetwork">
<!-- Internet Permission -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.YogaNetwork">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".DashboardActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" 
/>

            <category 
android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if you want to ask for multiple permissions. You can do this.

```
private ArrayList<String> permisos;

private void someMethod()
{
      ..

      verificarPermisos(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE );
      verificarPermisos(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION );
      verificarPermisos(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION );
      if (permisos.size()!=0)
      {
         solicitarPermisos(permisos.toArray(new String[permisos.size()]));
      }

      ..

 }


@TargetApi(23)
void verificarPermisos(String permiso){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,permiso)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        permisos.add(permiso);
        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permiso)) {

        }

    }
}

@TargetApi(23)
void solicitarPermisos(String[] permiso){

    requestPermissions(permiso, 1);

}
```

First, I check if the permission is already granted or not with "*verificarPermisos()*" method. If they are not granted, I add them to "*permisos*" arraylist. Finally, the ungranted permissions are resquested passing them in a *String[]* array format.

Note that you can only request permissions since MashMellow(API 23) or higher. So, if your app is also targetting android versions before MashMellow you could use the "*@TargetApi()*" annotation and the permission methods only be called when the target is API 23 or higher.
Hope to help, greetings.

Answer (score 0):

**Checking every situation**

> if denied - showing Alert dialog to user why we need permission

```
public static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE= 1;


    private void askPermissions() {

    int permissionCheckStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE); 

   // we already asked for permisson & Permission granted, call camera intent
    if (permissionCheckStorage == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        //do what you want

    } else {

           // if storage request is denied
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("You need to give permission to access storage in order to work this feature.");
            builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.setPositiveButton("GIVE PERMISSION", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();

                    // Show permission request popup
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            });
            builder.show();

        } //asking permission for first time 
          else {
             // Show permission request popup for the first time
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AddWorkImageActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

                    }

    }
}
```

**Checking Permission Results**

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && permissions[0].equals(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                // check whether storage permission granted or not.
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //do what you want;
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

> you can just copy and paste this code, it works fine. change context(this) & permissions according to you.